# Is there a way to amend a specific gerrit in a relation chain

Tags: git, gerrit

I am relatively new to gerrit/git butam aware of the workflow where we are only dealing with just one gerrit ( i.e if we push a commit to review and if we get some feedback, then we address the feedback and do `git commit --amend` and push the changes again for review and the cycle continues until we are good to merge) .

My questions is more about what if we have multiple gerrits that form a relation chain, then in that case is there a way to modify a particular commit. For example we have branch A with three commits ( a, b and c all non reviewed ) and now i want to merge all those changes to branch B ( have them reviewed before we submit ) but the issue is that commit a depends on commit b and commit b depends on commit c . Now instead of just cheery picking just one gerrit at a time i want to cherry pick all the commits to the destination branch so that i can start the review process in parallel but that causes gerrit to indicate commits a,b and c forms a relation chain. Now if i cherry pick in the order c then b then a , then it looks like using `git commit --amend` i can only modify commit a , but what if i get feedback on commit b or commit c, is there a way in git/gerrit where i can make changes to a specif commit and push the new changes to the correct commit instead of relying on `git commit --amend` to only be able to edit the last commit. And also after the commit is modified what is the correct way to push the changes to the correct gerrit for review. Currently we push the changes using command  `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/xxx` Just want to make sure that it goes to the correct gerrit.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of how Gerrit works is correct and I recommend avoiding pushing a large number of commits for review. Try to edit these commits "in parallel" as much as possible without building on each other. After the review process, all commits are submitted and finally stacked.

Anyway, you can change commits in the middle of the relationship chain using the same process you're used to. After changing a commit in a relationship chain, simply rebase the commits based on it. This can be done automatically using the "Rebase" button in the Gerrit UI (if there are no conflicts) or manually by running "git rebase" "git commit --amend" and "git push" on your local repository.